# How do you tune Eclipse IDE? How do you use Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, ide

I've started to read the book "Code Craft" by Pete Goodliffe. The fourth chapter is about instruments that developer uses during his daily work; this chapter made me to review my work and I've seriously decided to make it easier with fully personalized IDE. Eclipse IDE is what I've started my learning from...

I've read documentation and found that it's really easy to do tasks routine from Eclipse. We are using Mantis for tracking tasks and it was great surprise for me to find out Mantis Connector for Mylyn.

Also I was pretty glad to see SVN client integrated into Eclipse IDE.

Also I've found UML2 tool for Eclipse, but was disappointed because there is no any graphic interface for building diagramms. (Or, maybe, I'm was searching in wrong place?)

- What useful plugins do you use in your daily work?
- How do you use Eclipse for collaboration in your team?
- Do you have any links about intergration Eclipse IDE experience in dev. team?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you do web development with Tomcat, the [Sysdeo launcher plugin](http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html) is handy.  Also, it is definitely worth some time to learn the more important keyboard shortcuts.  Good lists [here](http://rayfd.wordpress.com/2007/05/20/10-eclipse-navigation-shortcuts-every-java-programmer-should-know/) and [here](http://eclipse.dzone.com/news/effective-eclipse-shortcut-key) (with a little overlap).  Ctrl-Shift-R and Ctrl-Shift-T are especially vital when you have a large code base.

Answer (score 0):

I use eclipse for Java, so that's pretty much the extent of my experience as far as languages go.

Subclipse (which I guess you are using) and the built in JUnit tool are the two things I use the most.

Also, hitting F3 will take you to the definition of a method, and F4 will tell you which classes implement a given interface.

Eclipse will also generate your getters and Setters (RightClick->source->Generate Getters/Setters)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, especially for hot keys.

Answer (score 0):

My two favorite hotkeys in Eclipse are

control-alt-up/down : copy the current line or selected lines
  alt-up/down : move the current line or selected lines

Get used to these two and your coding speed improves drastically!